# How to get a CrudRepository instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

Recently I have been following this guide on how to persist data in a in-memory H2 database using Spring Boot:

- Guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
- Source code: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa/

In it, one first defines a `CustomerEntity` class and then a `CustomerRepository` interface. Then, in the main class, a lot of annotation magic is being done, which enables one to simple "have" a `CustomerRepository` instance, which can be used to persist data to the database, retrieve it, etc.

This is all fine, however, I need to use such a `CustomerRepository` instance outside of the main class, inside another class. Since the tutorial does not reveal the magic that was done to make it available in the main class, I do not know how to make it happen in the class that I need it in.

I have been trying to figure this out almost all day long, but I just get lost inside a jungle of articles all trying to explain which Spring annotation does what, and I am really exhausted now.

I want to do something like this:

```
public class Foo {

  private CustomerRepository repo;

  // ...

  public void storeCustomer(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.repository.save(new Customer(firstName, lastName));
  }

}
```

I would be very happy about some hints.

Comment: You need to make Foo into a spring managed bean by annotating it with @ Component and then use @ Autowired on the customerrepository-field. Spring dependency injection :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! However, when I call `storeCustomer` then, I get a `NullPointerException`...

Comment: @dwightschrute What does your package structure look like?  By default, Spring Boot will look in packages recursively beginning where you've defined @ SpringBootApplication.  So make sure that the package containing Foo is a child of your Main class.

Comment: There really is no package structure, all source files are siblings in the root directory. `Application.java` has the main method that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, and `Foo.java` is in the same package.

Comment: How can packages be children of classes?

Comment: @dwightschrute They can be children of the package that your Main class is in.  Typically, Spring Boot projects would have a top-level package `com.example` which contains `Application.java` annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`  Then you'd have sub-packages like `com.example.entity` and `com.example.repository`, etc.  The default Component Scanning begins at the package containing Application.java and any sub-packages therein.  A common issue is Users will have `mypackage`& `myentities`.  That requires additional configuration to work.  Obviously seeing your project would make things easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to autowire CustomerRepository object and also need to autowire Foo object foo object from your controller.

```
public class Foo {

@Autowire
private CustomerRepository repo;

  public void storeCustomer(String firstName, String lastName) {
  this.repo.save(new Customer(firstName, lastName));
  } 
}
```

And u need to autowire the Foo object from controller/restcontroller to call storeCustomer method.

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController{

  @Autowired
  Foo obj;
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="addNewCustomer")
   public String addnewCustomer(){      
      obj.storeCustomer("firstname","lastname");
      return "";

   }
}
```

And define your autowired beans in any class  using @Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public Foo obj(){
      return new Foo();
  }
  @Bean
  public CustomerRepository repo(){
      return new CustomerRepository();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example

```
@Component
public class Foo{

  @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repo;

  // ...

  public void storeCustomer(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.repository.save(new Customer(firstName, lastName));
  }

}
```

If you need to try it, you can use a 'CommandLineRunner'

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner myRunner(Foo myFooService){

  myFooService.storeCustomer("name","lastname");

}
```